# RegEx not working in JavaScript Quiz

Tags: javascript, regex, arrays

I have this quiz thing in JavaScript and CSS, it checks an input against an array of answers. It was working fine before I tried to implement RegEx. I put in RegEx to try and make the answers case insensitive. Here is the new code:

```
function check(a) {

    var str=a;
    var patt = new RegExp("/"+key[window.questnum]+"/i");
    var anscheck=patt.test(str);


    if(anscheck==true){
        document.getElementById('quiz').style.backgroundColor="#44ee99";
        setTimeout(function() {
            document.getElementById('quiz').style.backgroundColor="#44aaff";
        }, 500); 
        newquest(); }
    else if(a=="") {
        document.getElementById('answer').style.backgroundColor="#00eeee";
        setTimeout(function() {
            document.getElementById('answer').style.backgroundColor="#FFFFFF";
        }, 250); 
        }
    else {
        document.getElementById('quiz').style.backgroundColor="#ee9944";
        setTimeout(function() {
            document.getElementById('quiz').style.backgroundColor="#44aaff";
        }, 500); 
    }
```

Here is the old working code:

```
function check(a) {
    if(a==key[window.questnum]){
[[etc changing color]]
```

Any and all help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use String.toLowerCase() on both strings you can then check equality.

Comment: Hey, thanks for that, it worked great. No RegEx required! still new to it.

Comment: RegEx are reputed to be slow so if you can avoid them it's better to ;). (you can accept my answer if it works so that your question doesn't appear in the unanswered part of the website)

Comment: Yeah i wanted to but I had to wait like 5 mins. Done it now. Thanks for your help, but I ended up sticking with RegEx to allow more possible answers.

Answer (score 1):

You should put the "i" flag separately when using new RegExp().

Try:

```
var patt = new RegExp(key[window.questnum], "i");
```

Comment: Yes, and you should also mention that the regex literal delimiters `/` should not be included when passing a string to the `RegExp` constructor.